# Google AppEngine Getting 403 forbidden trying to update cron.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

I am following the [docs on how to backup datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export) using AppEngine. 
I am performing a `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` command on a GCE VM that is meant to update a cronjob in AppEngine. the GCE VM and AppEngine cron are in the same project, and I have granted AppEngine admin to the GCE VM via a default Service Account. When I run this on my local machine, it updates fine. However on the GCE instance, thats where issues arise

Here are the files

### app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: cloud-datastore-admin
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "latest"
handlers:
- url: /cloud-datastore-export
  script: cloud_datastore_admin.app
  login: admin
```

### cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "Daily Cloud Datastore Export"
  url: /cloud-datastore-export?namespace_id=&output_url_prefix=gs://<my-project-id>-bucket
  target: cloud-datastore-admin
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

### cloud_datastore_export.yaml

```
import datetime
import httplib
import json
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class Export(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    access_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore')
    app_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
    output_url_prefix = self.request.get('output_url_prefix')
    assert output_url_prefix and output_url_prefix.startswith('gs://')
    if '/' not in output_url_prefix[5:]:
      # Only a bucket name has been provided - no prefix or trailing slash
      output_url_prefix += '/' + timestamp
    else:
      output_url_prefix += timestamp
    entity_filter = {
        'kinds': self.request.get_all('kind'),
        'namespace_ids': self.request.get_all('namespace_id')
    }
    request = {
        'project_id': app_id,
        'output_url_prefix': output_url_prefix,
        'entity_filter': entity_filter
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    }
    url = 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%s:export' % app_id
    try:
      result = urlfetch.fetch(
          url=url,
          payload=json.dumps(request),
          method=urlfetch.POST,
          deadline=60,
          headers=headers)
      if result.status_code == httplib.OK:
        logging.info(result.content)
      elif result.status_code >= 500:
        logging.error(result.content)
      else:
        logging.warning(result.content)
      self.response.status_int = result.status_code
    except urlfetch.Error:
      logging.exception('Failed to initiate export.')
      self.response.status_int = httplib.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
        ('/cloud-datastore-export', Export),
    ], debug=True)
```

**The Error I'm getting is**

```
Configurations to update:
descriptor:      [/usr/local/sbin/pluto/<my-project-id>/datastore/cron.yaml]
type:            [cron jobs]
target project:  [<my-project-id>]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Updating config [cron]...
failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
  Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
  You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u'e~<my-project-id>').
```

I have checked other posts related to this, however they seem to deal with an old version/deployment of appengine

### Service Accounts!

[image: Service Account Permissions]

Answer (score 3):

From [Deploying using IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/granting-project-access#deploying_using_iam_roles):

> To grant a user account the ability to deploy to App Engine:
>
> 2. Click Add member to add the user account to the project and then select all of the roles for that account by using the dropdown menu:
>
>    - **Required** roles to allow an account to deploy to App Engine:
>
>      a. Set the one of the following roles:
>
>      - Use the **App Engine > App Engine Deployer** role to allow the account to deploy a version of an app.
>      - To also allow the `dos.yaml` or `dispatch.yaml` files to be deployed with an app, use the **App Engine > App Engine Admin** role
>          instead.
>
>      The user account now has adequate permission to use the [Admin API to deploy apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview).
>
>      b. To allow use of App Engine [tooling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp) to deploy apps, you must also give the user account the **Storage > Storage Admin** role
>        so that the tooling has permission to upload to [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/).
>    - **Optional**. Give the user account the following roles to grant permission for uploading additional configuration files:
>
>      - **Cloud Scheduler > Cloud Scheduler Admin** role: Permissions for uploading `cron.yaml` files.

Potentially of interest:

- [Deployments with predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#deployments_with_predefined_roles)
- [Predefined roles comparison matrix](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Okay after some tinkering. I added the project editor role to the service account linked to the GCE instance running my server. I am not fully aware if this is the role with least priviledge to enable this to work.

[image]

Comment: -1 Suggesting to add Project Editor role just to enable cron deployment for AppEngine is a massive over-provision of permissions. Project Editor encapsulates over 1000 individual permissions so from a security standpoint nobody should do this.