# How can I snapshot the state of my Google App Engine application and upload it to a separate Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, snapshot

I am setting up a relationship where two Google App Engine applications (A and B) need to share data. B needs to read data from A, but A is not directly accessible to B. Both A and B currently use Google Datastore (NOT persistent disk).

I have an idea where I take a snapshot of A's state and upload it to a separate Google Cloud Storage location. This location can be read by B.

Is it possible to take a snapshot of A using Google App Engine and upload this snapshot (perhaps in JSON) to a separate Google Cloud Storage location to be read from by B? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Datastore [managed export/import service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities):

> This page describes how to export and import Cloud Firestore in
>   Datastore mode entities using the managed export and import service.
>   The managed export and import service is available through the gcloud
>   command-line tool and the Datastore mode Admin API ([REST](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/),
>   [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/)).

You can see a couple of examples described in a bit more details in these more or less related posts:

- [Google AppEngine Getting 403 forbidden trying to update cron.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628800/google-appengine-getting-403-forbidden-trying-to-update-cron-yaml)
- [Transferring data from product datastore to local development environment datastore in Google App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756120/transferring-data-from-product-datastore-to-local-development-environment-datast)

You may need to take extra precautions:

- if you need data consistency (exports are not atomic)
- to handle potential conflicts in entity key IDs, especially if using manually-generated ones or referencing them in other entities

If `A is not directly accessible to B` isn't actually something intentional and you'd be OK with allowing B to access A then that's also possible. The datastore can be accessed from **anywhere**, even from outside Google Cloud (see [How do I use Google datastore for my web app which is NOT hosted in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051453/how-do-i-use-google-datastore-for-my-web-app-which-is-not-hosted-in-google-app-e/42060551#42060551)). It might be a bit tricky to set it up, but once that's done it's IMHO a smoother sharing approach than the export/import one.